# How to skip a task if a file has been modified

Tags: ansible

I am working on ansible-playbook, granted I am kind of new at this. Anyways, in the ansible playbook, I modified a file and when I rerun the playbook, I don’t want that file to be modified again.

```
- name: Check if the domain config.xml has been edited
  stat: path={{ domainshome }}/{{ domain_name }}/config/config.xml
  register: config

- name: Config.xml modified
  debug: msg="The Config.xml has been modified"
  when: config.changed

- name: Edit the config.xml - remove extra file-store bad tag
  shell: "sed -i '776,780d' {{ domainshome }}/{{ domain_name }}/config/config.xml"
  when: config.changed
```

When I run for the first time, it skips this step.

I need this step to run once and skip if the playbook is rerun.

I am trying to write ansible-playbook and remove entries from config file only when it’s executed for the first time so that it can run the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Remove entries from config file only when it’s executed for the first time."*

A: It's possible to use the *`creates`* parameter of the [*shell*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-execute-shell-commands-on-targets) module to make sure the configuration file has been edited only once. For example

```
- name: Edit the config.xml - remove extra file-store bad tag
  shell: "sed -i '776,780d' {{ domainshome }}/{{ domain_name }}/config/config.xml"
  args:
    creates: "{{ domainshome }}/{{ domain_name }}/config/config.xml.lock"
- name: Create lock file
  file:
    state: touch
    path: "{{ domainshome }}/{{ domain_name }}/config/config.xml.lock"
```

---

Notes

- Quoting: *`creates: A filename, when it already exists, this step will not be run.`*
- Fit the path and name of the lock file to your needs
- *`stat`* module returns information about a file only and never changes a file. The registered variable *`register: config`* in this task would never report a file has been changed.
- *`file`* module and *`state: touch`* is not idempotent. Quoting: *`an existing file or directory will receive updated file access and modification times (similar to the way touch works from the command line)`*.
- A better solution would be to modify the command and create the lock file along with sed. For example *`"sed -i ... && touch /path-to-lockfile/lockfile"`*.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir!